# Auto increment in xml attributes

Tags: xml

Can we use auto increment attribute in xml?

Comment: You haven't provided enough context for anybody to answer your question.  What database? What environment?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101885/auto-increment-for-simplexml

Comment: You can following the link. 

this may help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101885/auto-increment-for-simplexml

Answer (score 2):

XML is a file format, not a database.

Auto increment has no meaning in an XML file context.

From the main w3 page on [XML](http://www.w3.org/XML/):

> Extensible Markup Language (XML) is a simple, very flexible text format

Answer (score 0):

No, an attribute name cannot contain a space, so `auto increment` is not a permissible attribute.

You could use `auto-increment`, `auto_increment` or `autoincrement`  (or any capitalisation thereof)